# Change Action Bar onPressed color

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I cannot figure out how to change the action bar items "onPressed" color on Android. I'm not talking about the action bar background color but about the blue over state. How can I change the color of this or at least get rid of it? For instance the App Icon with the homeAsUpIndicator.

I tried to change the action bar style and also the menu item style but nothing worked.

Thanks

*EDIT*
Here is my implementation so far:

My style xml:

```
<style name="Theme.AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:selectableItemBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/fadein</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/fadeout</item>        
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbarheader</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/actionbarheader</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/actionbarheader</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBarTitle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/actionbarlogo</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/app_icon</item>>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTitle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Then I have a drawable for the actionbarogo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/actionbarlogo_on" android:state_pressed="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/actionbarlogo_on" android:state_focused="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/actionbarlogo_off"/>
</selector>
```

My menu xml for the action bar items:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/ContactsMode"
        android:icon="@drawable/actionbarcontacts"
        android:title="@string/contacts"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
</menu>
```

and finally, the item's drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/actionbarcontacts_on" android:state_pressed="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/actionbarcontacts_on" android:state_focused="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/actionbarcontacts_off"/>
</selector>
```

Here is how I create the Menu Items for the ActionBar:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.actionbarlogo);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {        
         MenuItem item= menu.findItem(R.id.ContactsMode);
         if(ContactsButton)
             item.setVisible(true);      
         else
            item.setVisible(false);

         return true;   
    }
```

Comment: Backgrounds of which items in the action bar do you want to change? The menu items only? Or do you want to change the pressed background of all the items there (the app icon with the homeAsUpIndicator, overflow icon)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it. There was a parent activity changing the theme in the onCreate method...

I didn't know that you could set the theme programmatically within the activity with:

```
setTheme(R.style.MyTheme);
```

Answer (score 38):

To set the background for app icon together with the homeAsUpIndicator (there is a common background for these two icons) you have to set `android:actionBarItemBackground` item in the theme. The theme has to contain something like this (I assume that you use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)):

```xml
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <!-- for ActionBarSherlock -->
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/my_background</item>
    <!-- for native ActionBar -->
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/my_background</item>
</style>
```

Where the drawable `drawable/my_background.xml` would be a [StaleListDrawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList), containing something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/my_background_pressed" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/my_background_normal" />
</selector>
```

To disable the background completely, you can set a transparent background, or value `@null` in the theme might also work.

The theme item `android:actionBarItemBackground` sets the background for app icon and homeAsUpIndicator. But it also sets **the default background for menu items, overflow icon and background for title**. These backgrounds can be overridden.

**Menu items**

To change the menu item background set a proper `(android:)actionButtonStyle` in the theme like this:

```xml
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonStyle</item>
</style>
```

And `MyActionButtonStyle` will contain something like this:

```xml
<style name="MyActionButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/my_background</item>
</style>
```

**Overflow icon**

And finally, to change the overflow icon background set a proper`android:actionOverflowButtonStyle` in the theme like this:

```xml
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyOverflowButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyOverflowButtonStyle</item>
</style>
```

And `MyOverflowButtonStyle` will contain something like this:

```xml
<style name="MyOverflowButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/my_background</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Hey Tomik. Thanks for your answer. I tried it (see question edit) but I still have the Holo blue overlay...

Comment: I checked your code and as long as you don't use ActionBarSherlock it looks good and should disable the blue drawable in pressed state. Have you set the theme for an Activity properly? Just one note: `android:actionButtonStyle` is supposed to be placed in the theme instead of action bar style (no effect there), but this mistake should not affect the desired outcome.

Comment: Could it be the way I create the menu items (See edit)? I have to change the home icon at run-time because I use something different than the app's logo.

Comment: No, that should not have any effect. Does your other action bar theme settings work? How do you set the theme in manifest? Btw: you don't have to set the icon in code it can be done via themes together with some manifest settings.

Comment: In the manifest the theme is set for the application and the activities.

Comment: @Tomik Have you found a workaround for the change to work with actionbarsherlock