# set onPressed color action bar programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I have done some research, looked at this question but it didn't have the answers I was looking for. 
[Change Action Bar onPressed color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845549/change-action-bar-onpressed-color).
It is doing the same thing but is not what I am looking for, as I want to set the action bar color programatically, as I need to change the color by user preference. Here is how I get the action bar

```
ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
```

Any help with setting the color for when the back button or an item in the menu is tapped would be great. Thanks :)

Comment: you want to change button background color or actionbar background color??

Comment: @calvinfly no I want to change the onPressed color the

Comment: oh, you have to create StateListDrawable and set it into button background

Answer (score 0):

to change actionbar background, try this

```
bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xff00DDED));
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code into your oncreate method:

```
ActionBar actions = getActionBar();
        actions.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FF3300")));
```